# jQuery: Assign class on clicked element of multiple count

Tags: jquery, class

I have a list of clickable elements, all with same class names. I want to assign the clicked element a class `active` and remove `active` from all other elements simultaneously. How do I do it through jQuery?

```
<div class="container">  
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element active"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just hook `click` on `.element` elements, remove `active` from any `.element` elements that have it, and add it to the clicked one:

```
$(".element").click(function() {
    $(".element.active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

More: [`jQuery/$`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1), [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click), [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass), [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass)

Comment: That was embarrassing simple. :D

Answer (score 2):

use `addClass()` and `.siblings()` this way:

```
$('.element').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Here `$(this)` is the current element which is been clicked so this element gets the class `.active` and `.siblings().removeClass()` is removing other `.active` class applied on other element.

#### [CHECKOUT THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uVxQs/)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('.element').click(function(){
    $('.element').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.element').click(function() {
  $('.element').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```